# To which statement is Artin referring in this proof about factoring integer polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following is an excerpt in Artin's *Algebra* (2nd ed., pg. 371)

We pose the problem of factoring an integer polynomial
$$
f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0,
$$
with $a_n\neq 0$. Linear factors can be found fairly easily.

> **Lemma 12.4.2b**
>
> A primitive polynomial $b_1x+b_0$ divides $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if
>   and only if the rational number $-b_0/b_1$ is a root of $f$.
>
> ***Proof.***
>
> (b) According to Theorem $\color{red}{12.3.10(c)}$, $b_1x+b_0$ divides
>   $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if and only if it divides $f$ in
>   $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and this is true if and only if $x+b_0/b_1$  divides
>   $f$, i.e., $-b_0/b_1$ is a root.

On the same page, Theorem 12.3.10 does not have a part (c).

> **Theorem 12.3.10**
>
> If $R$ is a unique factorization domain, the polynomial ring
>   $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ in any number of variables is a unique
>   factorization domain.

Does anyone know about this typo? If so, to which statement is Artin referring?

Comment: It looks like 12.3.6(a) to me. I'll let you check that and write it up as an answer to your own question if you agree.

Comment: Sure: one direction of the equivalence is easy and the other is 12.3.6.(a). Go and write your answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the following piece of the proof of Lemma 12.4.2b.

> $b_1x+b_0$ divides
>   $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if and only if it divides $f$ in
>   $\mathbb{Q}[x]\quad(1)$

Theorem 12.3.6(a) on pg. 369 says

> Let $f_0$ be a primitive polynomial, and let $g$ be an integer polynomial. If $f_0$ divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $f_0$ divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ holds for $(1)$ by the above theorem since $b_1x+b_0$ is primitive by the statement of the lemma; however, $(\Rightarrow)$ does not follow from that theorem. To get $(\Rightarrow)$, we know that if $b_1x+b_0$ divides $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, it also divides $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.